# how can access to the pendingIntent variable from called service

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

my code for **AlarmManager** :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, specialCode, intent, 0);
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 30 * 1000, operation);
```

I wanna access to the `pendingIntent` variable from MyService.java to stop the repeating AlarmManager

how can I ?

**MyService.java**

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    if(condition){
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = what?//to access same pendingIntent
        G.alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
    }
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're `PendingIntent` just needs to "match".  You can accomplish what you're trying to do by setting it up the same way.  You're going to want to convert your `specialCode` to a constant or define an `Integer` without a value in `ids.xml` and let the system assign a value during compile.  By doing the latter you can guarantee that it will be 100% unique.  If you choose to use a generated ID then you'll use `this.getResources().getInteger(R.id.my_alarm)` in place of `specialCode`.

```
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, specialCode, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
```

[Android ids.xml Docs](https://developer.android.com/samples/ActionBarCompat-Basic/res/values/ids.html)

```
<resources>
    <item name="my_alarm" type="id"/>
</resources>
```

Comment: I wanna pass the `pendingIntent` variable to cancel it
when we are putting extra to intent ,pendingIntent not defined yet

Comment: As Bill explained, you don't need to pass a reference to the `PendingIntent` to your `Service`. Your service just needs to call `PendingIntent.getService()` with the same parameters as were used when the alarm was set.